# Javascript form validation multiple

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I must make form validation in javascript for 6 input types. When user press on submit button it should give him alert window about the fields which were not typed correctly  and turn them into red..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preveriFormo() {

        var ime = document.getElementById('ime');
        var priimek = document.getElementById('priimek');


        if (preveriCrke(ime, "Prosim uporabite samo crke za ime")) {
            if (preveriCrke(priimek, "Prosim uporabite samo crke za priimek")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function preveriCrke(element, sporocilo) {
        var crke = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if (element.value.match(crke)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            alert(sporocilo);
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>

<form onsubmit="return preveriFormo()" >
    Ime <input type='text' id='ime' /><br />
    Priimek <input type='text' id='priimek' /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Potrdi" />
</form>
```

My problem is that I dont know how to make alert window with list of not correctly writen fileds and change color( for all of them).. in my example forms are only checked one-by-one. I would really appriciate if anyone could him me a hint how to solve this

Comment: Don't forget to set the background colour back to the default for any fields that pass (to allow for if the user has corrected some of their previous errors and tries to submit again).

Comment: You should just use a js validation plugin. Makes life easier: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a `flag` variable.By default put the value to `false`.If any one of the validation fails then put `true`.
Than return flag

```
return flag;
```

Comment: Or the other way around - should return `false` if validation fails.

Comment: @PSR  
Thanks for this. But now alert windows are displayed one by one in order.. is it posible that there is only one alert window saying which fields were wrong/blank?

Comment: try to append all error messages into a string then show it in alert

Comment: @PSR 
Could you please give me an example how could I do that? I really have no idea about this... sorry, I am begginer :)